# Ember Select - set outlet to selection

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm looking to create a dropdown list and have it populated with values from my model.

```
App.CoursesRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function() {
      return Ember.RSVP.hash({
          mathcourses: this.store.find('mathcourse'),
          quickmathunits: this.store.find('quickmathunit'),
          cscourses: this.store.find('cscourse'),
          quickcsunits: this.store.find('quickcsunit'),
      })
  }

});


App.Mathcourse = DS.Model.extend({

    title: DS.attr('string'),

});

App.Mathcourse.FIXTURES = [
{id: 1,  title:'Algebra', math: true},
{id: 2,  title:'Geometry', math: false},
{id: 3,  title:'Algebra 2'},
{id: 4,  title:'Statistics'},
{id: 5, title:'Pre-Calculus'},
]
```

Is from the index.html

```
{{view Ember.Select
content= mathcourses
optionValuePath="content.id"
optionLabelPath="content.title"}}
```

is from the app.js

Does anyone know what code to add to add in order to make this dropdown selection function as required? The list works as desired but I'm not sure how to make it use the IDs as link-to when chosen. I'd like it to select between the different subpages, as an alternate menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the selection to a variable inside the controller:

```
{{view Ember.Select
content= mathcourses
optionValuePath="content.id"
optionLabelPath="content.title"
value=selected}}
```

And then just create a computed property observing that variable and make it redirect were you want.

Controller:

```
selected: '',

MyComputedProperty: function(){
  //REDIRECT
}.property('selected'),
```

Redirect: http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/redirection/